# Nodemailer works on localhost, but when express API is hosted on Vercel email is sent, but not received

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have implemented confirmation email once appointment is booked. After testing on localhost, email is sent and received. However once API is built and hosted on Vercel, it sends an email, but email is never received. I am using IONOS as email provider and custom domain. The message I get after email is sent on the server is this:

Message sent: <b125e493-1555-72d5-96ac-6f72fa258cc1@[This is my domain].com>
Email sent successfully
Appointment booked successfully

I have tried to use different IONOS port 587 instead of 465, but still was the same.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EM_HOST,
    port: process.env.EM_PORT,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EM_USER,
      pass: process.env.EM_PASS,
    }
});

export default function sendEmail(email){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter.sendMail({
      from: "[thisismyemail@email.com]", // sender address
      to: email, // list of receivers
      subject: "Appointment Booking Confirmation", // Subject line
      text: "Your appointment has been booked", // plain text body
    }, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log(email);
        console.log("Message sent:", info.messageId);
        resolve(info.messageId);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```
router.post("/book-appointment", async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        await db.query("INSERT INTO appointments (date) VALUES ($1)", [req.body.res_date]);
        try {
            await sendEmail(req.body.res_email);
            console.log("Email sent successfully");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending email:", error);
        }
        console.log("Appointment booked successfully");
        res.status(201).json({ message: "Appointment booked successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error inserting appointment:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Error booking appointment" });
    }
});
```